# Mod_Perl AddType .pl execution on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, mod-perl, mod-php

I've recently been using PHP via mod_php, and I assumed that getting mod_perl running properly was going to require a similar setup:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

unfortunately this does nothing with mod_perl using:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-perl .pl
```

the entire script is simply sent out with a

```
Content-Type: application/x-httpd-perl
```

header.

Why doesn't mod_perl execute scripts flagged as `application/x-httpd-perl` as mod_php does with scripts flagged as `application/x-httpd-php`?

Answer (score 0):

They use different approaches to execute scripts.

This document http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html describes how to install mod_perl handler for scripts in some directory. The *"Registry Scripts"* section is exactly what you need.

Comment: Um, why is there `Options +ExecCGI`? I don't want to enable CGI for every single page on the server; that's part of the reason I'm not using CGI. Also, my question is why can't I just set `application/x-httpd-perl` and have every .pl file outside of `/cgi-bin` run.

Comment: Again, you should consider that the inner logic of mod_perl and mod_php is different, you may look at differencies in execution of php and perl scripts in the CGI mode, for example. You don't have to enable CGI for all the pages and locations, but only for the location with your scripts which you want to use with mod_perl.

Comment: The problem is I want to be able to use Perl everywhere without turning on CGI. Do you know why mod_perl needs ExecCGI? Is there some kind of workaround to having CGI on for the whole server just for mod_perl?